# Database Methods on Entities

Tags: design-patterns

I'm starting a new project and there is some internal debate on the right approach to writing objects to a database.

CRUD operations require 3 parameters: DB Handle, DB Name, Collection Name.

All objects are derived from a BaseEntity object (which has the standard Id, Creation Time, Update Time, etc).

The first approach is to put the CRUD operations in the BaseEntity class.  So you can do:

```
var obj = new MyObject() { ... }
obj.Insert(DB, DBName, CollectionName);
```

The second approach is to create a class that controls the CRUD operations:

```
var collection = new Collection(DB, DBName, CollectionName);
var obj = new MyObject() { ... };
collection.Insert(obj);
```

I have my preferred method (not saying which) but what are some of the possible pros/cons of each solution?

The language in use is C# but I don't think that really matters.

Comment: the second is the repository pattern and is better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `MyObject` is some model class that represents some concept in your domain, then *separation of concerns* suggests that database logic should be handled separately – leading to a separate collection or repository object. This solution also seems to be far more convenient because now I don't have to pass separate DB/DbName/CollectionName objects around.

See also:

- Single Responsibility Principle,
- Cohesion (if the same code is responsible for different things this is not very cohesive)
- Coupling (if the model class is responsible for database logic, it is coupled to the database's interface)

**However** either solution is arguably fine. More important than choosing the slightly better solution is to be consistent within your code base and ecosystem. Many, many successful projects use an ActiveRecord style approach where the domain model is responsible for its own persistence, and this is *perfectly fine* as well.

In particular, there are often cross-cutting concerns like serialization or persistence that are needed for all your objects. The “single responsibility” for this concern can be argued either way: if the object is responsible for its own persistence, then all the functionality related to that object is nicely grouped into one cohesive class. Alternatively: if a separate repository object is responsible for the persistence of classes, then all persistence logic is nicely grouped into one cohesive class.

The choice between these alternatives is often but not always arbitrary. Things that are expected to change together should be grouped together. If you are likely to add new classes or change how an individual class is persisted, then keeping the persistence logic in the class seems sensible. In contrast, if you are more likely to change the persistence mechanism (e.g. switching to a completely different database), then using the repository pattern seems more sensible. But when all of those classes are part of the same project/solution, they are effectively grouped either way – a too fine-grained view is not always helpful.